# Is it possible to know the ip address of the bot connector for bot service

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

Currently we have the bot application hosted on premise and the server is behind a firewall, but our bot connector/bot channel registration still resides on Azure. I understand that when users send messages it has to go through the connector before reaching our bot application. Is there a way to find out what the ip address of the connector is so we can open up a port/whitelist an ip to allow the messages to come into the bot application?

Comment: Why do you believe that adds to your security envelope since you already do JWT token validation on all requests? You do DO that, right?

Comment: @evilSnobu not my decision, company policy

Comment: @yfan183 - did you get this figured out?  I'd like to get the IP to ban a certain user from continually joining the chat and abusing the members.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to find out what the ip address of the connector

As dandriscoll said in this github issue:[Whitelist for bot connector service](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1318), there is no published list of IP addresses for bot connector service.

Besides, if your company indeed need a whitelist, you can find the Azure IP ranges here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=41653.